# MySQL char set conversion for whole database - [ISO-8859-1]to [UTF-8]

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

Normally this is a pretty common question, I've read through lots of threads here on SO about converting a whole db to `UTF-8`.

..

However, I've tried a few php scripts in avail.

My problem is while my db is `ISO-8859-1` none of the content is encoded in ISO-8859-1.

In my db an ampersand is `&`

a British pound symbol is `£`

..
The scripts i have tried complete remove "`£450.00`" from string "s`pecial offer £450.00 this week only`"

Comment: Why do you need an external PHP script to do the conversion?

Comment: I just need a way of converting it without command line. Could be with php could be with phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://www.fractalizer.ru/frpost_162/php-mysql-batch-changing-charset-and-collation-on-databases/

latin1 allows symbols in 0x80-0xFF and conversion using MySQL native functions should go allright. Make backup anyway.

Comment: Hi there, this had the same effect as when i manually change the collation on a test column: `From £470 per week` becomes `From â£470 per week` ?

Comment: So, the symbol is not stripped and that's good. Why not to go through DB afterwards replacing `â£` with `£` using PHPMyAdmin or simple UPDATE/STR_REPLACE queries?

Comment: Yep, i guess my concern is that if this symbol was not converted, how many other might there be that I'm not yet aware of! is `£` a special case?